# JavaScript streamlining

Tags: javascript

Hi There I am developing the interactivity of a client site and I feel like the JS for my button functionality and the carousel.fader windows is built a little redundantly. Can someone take a look at this code and see if it can be simplified more so as to decrease page load time and really just to clean up the JS. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
function cycleImages(){
  $('.fader').each(function(){
      var $active = $(this).find('.active');
      var $next = ($(this).find('.active').next().length > 0) ? $(this).find('.active').next() : $(this).find('img:first');
      $next.css('z-index',2);//move the next image up the pile
      $active.fadeOut(1500,function(){//fade out the top image
          $active.css('z-index',1).show().removeClass('active');//reset the z-index and unhide the image
          $next.css('z-index',7).addClass('active');//make the next image the top one
      });
  });
}

function cycleImages2(){
  $('.about-fader').each(function(){
      var $active = $(this).find('.active');
      var $next = ($(this).find('.active').next().length > 0) ? $(this).find('.active').next() : $(this).find('img:first');
      $next.css('z-index',2);//move the next image up the pile
      $active.fadeOut(1500,function(){//fade out the top image
          $active.css('z-index',1).show().removeClass('active');//reset the z-index and unhide the image
          $next.css('z-index',7).addClass('active');//make the next image the top one
      });
  });
}

function cycleImages3(){
  $('.contact-fader').each(function(){
      var $active = $(this).find('.active');
      var $next = ($(this).find('.active').next().length > 0) ? $(this).find('.active').next() : $(this).find('img:first');
      $next.css('z-index',2);//move the next image up the pile
      $active.fadeOut(1500,function(){//fade out the top image
          $active.css('z-index',1).show().removeClass('active');//reset the z-index and unhide the image
          $next.css('z-index',7).addClass('active');//make the next image the top one
      });
  });
}

function cycleImages4(){
  $('.sourcing-fader').each(function(){
      var $active = $(this).find('.active');
      var $next = ($(this).find('.active').next().length > 0) ? $(this).find('.active').next() : $(this).find('img:first');
      $next.css('z-index',2);//move the next image up the pile
      $active.fadeOut(1500,function(){//fade out the top image
          $active.css('z-index',1).show().removeClass('active');//reset the z-index and unhide the image
          $next.css('z-index',5).addClass('active');//make the next image the top one
      });
  });
}

function cycleImages5(){
  $('.consulting-fader').each(function(){
      var $active = $(this).find('.active');
      var $next = ($(this).find('.active').next().length > 0) ? $(this).find('.active').next() : $(this).find('img:first');
      $next.css('z-index',2);//move the next image up the pile
      $active.fadeOut(1500,function(){//fade out the top image
          $active.css('z-index',1).show().removeClass('active');//reset the z-index and unhide the image
          $next.css('z-index',5).addClass('active');//make the next image the top one
      });
  });
} 

function cycleImages6(){
  $('.installation-fader').each(function(){
      var $active = $(this).find('.active');
      var $next = ($(this).find('.active').next().length > 0) ? $(this).find('.active').next() : $(this).find('img:first');
      $next.css('z-index',2);//move the next image up the pile
      $active.fadeOut(1500,function(){//fade out the top image
          $active.css('z-index',1).show().removeClass('active');//reset the z-index and unhide the image
          $next.css('z-index',5).addClass('active');//make the next image the top one
      });
  });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".about-button").on("click", function(){
        $(".homepage-container").hide();
        $(".contact-container").removeClass("display-flex");
        $(".services-sourcing-container").removeClass("display-flex");
        $(".services-consulting-container").removeClass("display-flex");
        $(".services-installation-container").removeClass("display-flex");
        $(".about-container").addClass("display-flex");

    });

$(".home-button").on("click", function(){
        $(".homepage-container").show();
        $(".about-container").removeClass("display-flex");
        $(".services-sourcing-container").removeClass("display-flex");
        $(".services-consulting-container").removeClass("display-flex");
        $(".services-installation-container").removeClass("display-flex");
        $(".contact-container").removeClass("display-flex");
    });

$(".contact-button").on("click", function() {
        $(".homepage-container").hide();
        $(".about-container").removeClass("display-flex");
        $(".services-sourcing-container").removeClass("display-flex");
        $(".services-consulting-container").removeClass("display-flex");
        $(".services-installation-container").removeClass("display-flex");
        $(".contact-container").addClass("display-flex");
    })

$(".sourcing-button").on("click", function() {
        $(".homepage-container").hide();
        $(".about-container").removeClass("display-flex");
        $(".contact-container").removeClass("display-flex");
        $(".services-consulting-container").removeClass("display-flex");
        $(".services-installation-container").removeClass("display-flex");
        $(".services-sourcing-container").addClass("display-flex");
    })

$(".consulting-button").on("click", function() {
        $(".homepage-container").hide();
        $(".about-container").removeClass("display-flex");
        $(".contact-container").removeClass("display-flex");
        $(".services-sourcing-container").removeClass("display-flex");
        $(".services-installation-container").removeClass("display-flex");
        $(".services-consulting-container").addClass("display-flex");
    })

$(".installation-button").on("click", function() {
        $(".homepage-container").hide();
        $(".about-container").removeClass("display-flex");
        $(".contact-container").removeClass("display-flex");
        $(".services-sourcing-container").removeClass("display-flex");
        $(".services-consulting-container").removeClass("display-flex");
        $(".services-installation-container").addClass("display-flex");
    })

// run every 7s
    setInterval('cycleImages()', 5000);
    setInterval('cycleImages2()', 5000);
    setInterval('cycleImages3()', 5000);
    setInterval('cycleImages4()', 5000);
    setInterval('cycleImages5()', 5000);
    setInterval('cycleImages6()', 5000);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain selectors as you do in CSS: [jQuery Multiple selector documentation](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/).

Also, you indicate that `setInterval` must run every 7 seconds (in comment), set it up with `5000` (5 seconds): so i changed it in the code below.

So your code can look like this:

```
function cycleImages(){
    $('.fader, .about-fader, .contact-fader, .sourcing-fader, .consulting-fader, .installation-fader').each(function(){
        var $active = $(this).find('.active');
        var $next = ($(this).find('.active').next().length > 0) ? $(this).find('.active').next() : $(this).find('img:first');
        $next.css('z-index',2);//move the next image up the pile
        $active.fadeOut(1500,function(){//fade out the top image
            $active.css('z-index',1).show().removeClass('active');//reset the z-index and unhide the image
            $next.css('z-index',7).addClass('active');//make the next image the top one
        });
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".about-button, .home-button, .contact-button, .sourcing-button, .consulting-button, .installation-button").on("click", function(){
        if($(this).hasClass("about-button")) {
            $(".about-container").addClass("display-flex");
        } else {
            $(".about-container").removeClass("display-flex");
        }

        if($(this).hasClass("home-button")) {
            $(".homepage-container").show();
        } else {
            $(".homepage-container").hide();
        }

        if($(this).hasClass("contact-button")) {
            $(".contact-container").addClass("display-flex");
        } else {
            $(".contact-container").removeClass("display-flex");
        }

        if($(this).hasClass("sourcing-button")) {
            $(".services-sourcing-container").addClass("display-flex");
        } else {
            $(".services-sourcing-container").removeClass("display-flex");
        }

        if($(this).hasClass("consulting-button")) {
            $(".services-consulting-container").addClass("display-flex");
        } else {
            $(".services-consulting-container").addClass("display-flex");
        }

        if($(this).hasClass("installation-button")) {
            $(".services-installation-container").addClass("display-flex");
        } else {
            $(".services-installation-container").addClass("display-flex");
        }
    });

    // run every 7s
    setInterval('cycleImages()', 7000);
});
```

Comment: Im going to give this a try, and I agree with chaining the fader functions together, but will the click function work the way its supposed for every button the way you have it. it seems as though if and button is clicked it will simply add the class of display-flex to .about-container and nothing else

Comment: Sorry, i made a mistake while reading these lines. Answer updated.

Comment: Again, I will give this a try and close the question once completed. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I've simplified the `buttons` part.

Comment: refactoring of fader functions work great. Needed to make a few small tweaks to the revised `if/else` statements, but all in all works perfectly. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: need to revisit this question. had to reformat my code